# Adaptive Bitrate streaming in ios

Tags: streaming, bitrate

I am trying to implement adaptive bitrate streaming in ios. 
I have m3u8 url which has around 8-10 other url according to the bandwidth.

Question how to implement it in ios. Do we have a specific player which will automatically change the bandwidth or do we have to manual do it. 
If manually how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

iOS devices support HLS natively, which is Apple's Adaptive Bit rate streaming protocol.

You can find up to date info about specific codecs etc supported here :

- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/FrequentlyAskedQuestions/FrequentlyAskedQuestions.html